# Representation of chained XOR operation as a set of linear inequalities

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, boolean-algebra, integer-programming

I'm trying to solve an integer linear program (ILP) in which a constraint of the following kind must be met:

$x_1 \oplus x_2 \oplus \cdots \oplus x_n = 1$

where $\oplus$ is the binary *xor* operator.

The answer to [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/12102/express-boolean-logic-operations-in-zero-one-integer-linear-programming-ilp) question shows how to represent $y = x_1 \oplus x_2$ with linear inequalities. In an answer to [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/40737/express-xor-with-multiple-inputs-in-zero-one-integer-linear-programming-ilp) question there is an attempt to generalize the representation to more than two inputs, but the two answers seem to be inconsistent, since the latter doesn't even use inequalities.

So, the question is: how can I represent $y = x_1 \oplus x_2 \oplus \cdots \oplus x_n$ as set of linear inequalities?

Comment: What's wrong with the answer of the second link 
$y \le x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_n - 2t$,
$0 \le y \le 1$, and $y$, $t$ integer ?

Comment: The second answer doesn’t specify whether the variable t is boolean or an integer. So, refining my question (I confess my distraction, I didn’t see the inequalities in the second answer), is the variable t unconstrained/unbounded?

Comment: You can use it unbounded, or you can put a $t\gt 0$ constraint. Other constraints would be redundant.